# Does Shmita apply in Jordan?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, geography, shmita

Since the East bank of the Jordan River was given to shevet Reuven as an inheritance, was Shmita observed there as well? If so, does shmita still apply there?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=7&hilchos=40&perek=4&halocha=28&hilite= but http://www.din.org.il/2014/06/05/%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%98%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%97%D7%94/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just adding this answer due to the faulty translation in the accepted answer:

> [רמב"ם משנה תורה הלכות שמיטה ויובל](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/7704.htm#23)
>
> Rambam Mishneh Torah Laws of Shmita and Yovel
>
> כג  [כה] אין שביעית נוהגת אלא בארץ ישראל בלבד
>
> Shmita applies only in the Land of Israel itself.
>
> כה  [כח] עבר הירדן, שביעית נוהגת בה מדבריהם.
>
> On the eastern bank of the Jordan river, shmita is Rabbinic.

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi Shlomo Halbertal Shlita](http://www.mercazharav.org.il/default.asp?pg=3&id=468) concludes that Shmita applies in Jordan also. However only in the western part is it a Biblical obligation. In the Eastern part it is Midrabanan.

שרק בעבר הירדן המערבי – שבו שייכת קדושת השכינה כדברי התשב'ץ – שייכת מצות השביעית במלוא חובתה – מדאורייתא, מה שאין כן בעבר הירדן המזרחי – שביעית דרבנן

Comment: It's not the western part of Jordan. It's the west bank of the Jordan River, in Israel.

Comment: Yes, I believe the Hebrew is mistranslated.